# Implementing pop3 client

Tags: python, sockets

I am implementing Pop3 client in Python. I can connect to the pop3 server of my choice and I even get the first welcome message "+OK Hello, this is Seznam POP3 server unknown.\r\n" but after that the serve doesn't answer any of my messages and my client hangs on the recv call. Using telnet the server answers normally. I would expect this kind of answer "+OK Hello, this is Seznam POP3 server unknown." for my "User user" message.

Here is my code:

```
HOST = pop3.seznam.cz
PORT = 110

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, int(PORT)))
    data = s.recv(2048)
    print(data)
    num = s.send(b'USER user')
    print(num)
    data = s.recv(2048)

    print(repr(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
num = s.send(b'USER user')
```

The protocol requires each command to end with `\r\n`, i.e.

```
num = s.send(b'USER user\r\n')
```

See [RFC 1939](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt) for the actual standard.